# turn off keyboard-interactive authentication for plink

Tags: powershell, putty, plink

I am trying to write a script to automate router logins and run scripts using the below `plink` command:

```
plink routeraddress -l user@routeraddress -pw password
```

but getting the following:

```
"Access denied"
"Using keyboard-interactive authentication."
"password:"
```

When I manually uncheck the "Attempt 'keyboard-interactive' auth (SSH-2)" check box and login through PuTTY the login works fine.

Is there a way to disable keyboard-interactive authentication in plink similar to un-checking the box in PuTTY?

Comment: `plink -batch`?

Comment: with -batch I just get "Access Denied"

Comment: -v shows it's still attempting keyboard-interactive authentication with -batch

Comment: Are you certain it should be `-l user@routeraddress`, not `-l user`?

Comment: I've tried both and get the same result. 

user@routeraddress is what gets displayed when logged in via putty with keyboard-interactive authentication turned off so I thought that might be closer to the end solution